# Please find errors in my reasoning about field axioms

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory

We can define a field F with the following properties:

- Binary operations + (addition) and ⋅ (multiplication)
- Commutativity
- Associativity
- Identities
- Inverses
- Distributivity

Now, the additive inverse existence condition can be
equivalently replaced with the statement ∀a∈F 0a=0, because each
one is a consequence of the other.

The proof (assuming 0=0a):
$$0=0a=(1-1)a=a+(-1a)$$
Which means that for every a there exists an additive inverse,
more precisely it is -1a.

But now take the set {0,1} with logical conjunction for ⋅;
and *inclusive* disjunction for +. (so that 1+1=*1*)

- 1 doesn't have an additive inverse, as 1+1=1+0=1≠0
- concurrently, 0⋅0=0 and 0⋅1=0; so this indeed appears to be a field by the alternative condition.

Which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in my proof that 0=0a →-1a=-a, because -1∉{0,1}.